# namespace name 'GameType' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am creating an e-commerce website using ASP.NET web application and Visual Studio (project), but I am having trouble fixing my error.

When I try to run the code, it gives me the error:

[image]

The codes in my project do not show any error, so I am unsure where I went wrong. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: GameType may be the enum somehwere, you have to add the namespace to you class.

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya Thanks for responds. and yes i already placed my namespace from the app_code but still it showing the error during the compilation.

Comment: Please add the error as text, not as an image. Not everyone has the same eyesight. I can't read the marked error message for example. Plus: Screenreaders can't interpret images.